# Git: view the complete file for that commitId using magit

Tags: git, emacs, magit

On Gitweb, we can see the complete file of a commitId. On Emacs Magit, I can get to that commitID and see the diffs. Is it possible to see the complete file for that commitId via Magit?

Comment: I think you can (but I'm not sure I fully understand). Example: I see the commits log with `ll`, so I see commit ids on the first column. I choose a commit to see and I press enter: I see the diff for each file of the commit. Now I choose a file and press enter: I see all the file as it was at that specific commit (buffer named like "file-name.el~master~2~"). Does that answer your question ?

Comment: @Ehvince Your comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. I'm not sure of your workflow but I'll explain with the following use case.

I open the `magit-status` and I see the commits log with `ll`, so I see commit ids on the first column. I choose a commit to see and I press enter: I see the diff for each file of the commit. Now I choose a file and press enter: I see all the file as it was at that specific commit (the buffer is named something like "file-name.el~master~2~"). Does that answer your question ?

Comment: That works on my desktop which has Git 2.6.4. Emacs 24.5. But on my primary work environment Git 1.8.3 and same version of Emacs ands Magit, that doesn't.